# How many different numbers can be formed by using the seven digits $2,3,4,3,3,1,2$? How many with the digits $2,3,4,3,3,0,2$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many different numbers can be formed by using the seven digits $2,3,4,3,3,1,2$? How many with the digits $2,3,4,3,3,0,2$?

For the first part, there are seven digits, three $3$, two $2$, and one of each for the rest. $\dfrac{7!}{3!2!1!1!}=420$. This is the correct answer.

For the second part, there are seven digits, again three $3$, two $2$, and one of each for the rest. So the answer should be the same, $420$. But it is given as $360$. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you cannot have the first digit of a 7-digit number as 0. So let's try working it step by step. Find how many digits can be formed with 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2

$$\frac{6!}{3!2!1!}=60$$

Now we just have to find out how many ways we can put zero in the 7-digit number. With the exception of putting it as the first digit.

Notice that there are $7-1 = 6$ ways to put zero in a 7-digit number without being as the first digit.

So the total ways to put 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 0, 2 as a 7-digit number is 6 x 60, which is 360

Comment: But it's asking how many different numbers can be formed. So why can't $0$ be in the first digit? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, because your question said that why 360 and not 420. The answer is 420 if you assume that 0 can be as the first digit. 360 If you do not

Answer (score 2):

The number of 7-digit numbers of $2,3,4,3,3,0,2$ is

$\dfrac{7!}{3!2!1!1!}-\dfrac{6!}{3!2!1!}=420-60=360$

if $0$ is in the first digit, it can be written   $\dfrac{6!}{3!2!1!}$, (the number of arrangements of other six digits), different 7-digit number.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot have $0$ in the first digit, the correct expression will be: $\frac{6\times6!}{3!2!1!1!}=360$, where the first digit only has 6 choices.

Comment: Why can't $0$ be the first digit? $0333242$ is also a unique number. Also why is it $6!\cdot6$ in the numerator? Why isn't it just $6!$ since $0$ is discarded? Thanks.

Comment: It seems people have different views. I myself consider that, 0 as the first digit is negligent. You consider 0333232 as a 7 digit number, but I see it as a 6 digit number because 0 is negligent in my view.